# Format Scale for Choropleth map in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, plotly, choropleth

I have my sample dataset

```
    STATE          Count    POPESTIMATE2019 lat          long       IncidentPerInhabitant   Code
46  New Hampshire   1       1359711         43.206898   -71.537994  0.073545                NH
45  Idaho           2       1787065         43.617775   -116.199722 0.111915                ID
48  Vermont         1       623989          44.262436   -72.580536  0.160259                VT
47  Wyoming         1       578759          41.140259   -104.820236 0.172783                WY
38  Utah            6       3205958         40.777477   -111.888237 0.187152                UT
44  Maine           3       1344212         44.307167   -69.781693  0.223179                ME
.   .               .       .               .            .          .                       .
.   .               .       .               .            .          .                       .
.   .               .       .               .            .          .                       .
```

I am trying to plot a choropleth map with the following code:

```
fig1 = px.choropleth(df_merge2,
                    locations='Code',
                    color='IncidentPerInhabitant',
                    color_continuous_scale='Reds',
                    hover_name='STATE',
                    locationmode='USA-states',
                    labels={'IncidentPerInhabitant':'Incident Per 10000 Inhabitants '},
                    scope='usa')
fig1.show()
```

However, I am getting the values individually plotted on the legend rather than a scale (see image below)

[image: My map]

I would like my output to look more like this:

[image: Desired Output]

Comment: I ran your code on the 6 data items in your question and it displayed the color bar correctly. I was able to confirm the situation like the [official example](https://plotly.com/python/choropleth-maps/#using-builtin-country-and-state-geometries). The data type of the column you are specifying for the color is a float type, right? What version are you currently using? I don't know if this has anything to do with it.

Comment: `IncidentPerInhabitant` column is most likely a string - it's behaving like one and not a float. Turn the column into float type and try plotting again.

Answer (score 0):

I can reproduce your unexpected output if I cast the `IncidentPerInhabitant` column to string.

**Problem:** in your DataFrame, the `IncidentPerInhabitant` column is likely stored as a non-numeric data type.

**Solution:** before your plotting code, cast `IncidentPerInhabitant` to float:

```
df['IncidentPerInhabitant'] = df['IncidentPerInhabitant'].astype(float)
```